# Passing Input Pipeline to TensorFlow Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm a noob to TF so go easy on me.

I have to train a simple CNN from a bunch of images in a directory with labels.  After looking around a lot, I cooked up this code that prepares a TF input pipeline and I was able to print the image array.

```
    image_list, label_list = load_dataset()

    imagesq = ops.convert_to_tensor(image_list, dtype=dtypes.string)
    labelsq = ops.convert_to_tensor(label_list, dtype=dtypes.int32)

    # Makes an input queue
    input_q = tf.train.slice_input_producer([imagesq, labelsq],
                                                shuffle=True)

    file_content = tf.read_file(input_q[0])
    train_image = tf.image.decode_png(file_content,channels=3)
    train_label = input_q[1]

    train_image.set_shape([120,120,3])

    # collect batches of images before processing
    train_image_batch, train_label_batch = tf.train.batch(
        [train_image, train_label],
        batch_size=5
        # ,num_threads=1
    )

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # initialize the variables
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        # initialize the queue threads to start to shovel data
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        # print "from the train set:"
        for i in range(len(image_list)):
             print sess.run(train_image_batch)
        # sess.run(train_image)
        # sess.run(train_label)
        # classifier.fit(input_fn=lambda: (train_image, train_label),
        #                steps=100,
        #                monitors=[logging_hook])

        # stop our queue threads and properly close the session
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
        sess.close()
```

But looking at the MNIST example given in TF docs, I see they use a **cnn_model_fn** along with **Estimator** class.

I have defined my own **cnn_model_fn** and would like to combine the two.  Please help me on how to move forward with this.  This code doesn't work

```
classifier = learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir='./test_model')
classifier.fit(input_fn=lambda: (train_image, train_label),
steps=100,
monitors=[logging_hook])
```

It seems the pipeline is populated only when the session is run, otherwise its empty and it gives a ValueError 'Input graph and Layer graph are not the same'

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to tensorflow myself so take this with a grain of salt.

AFAICT, when you call any of the `tf` APIs that create "tensors" or "operations" they are created into a context called a `Graph`.

Further, I believe when the `Estimator` runs it creates a new empty `Graph` for each run. It populates the `Graph` by running `model_fn` and `input_fn` that are supposed to call `tf` APIs that add the "tensors" and "operations" in context of this fresh `Graph`.

The return values from `model_fn` and `input_fn` just provide references so that the parts could be connected correctly - the `Graph` already contains them.

However in this example the input operations have already been created before the `Estimator` created the `Graph` and thus their related operations have been added to the implicit default `Graph` (one is created automatically I believe). So when the `Estimator` creates a new one and populates the model with `model_fn` the input and model will be on two different graphs.

To fix this you need to change the `input_fn`. Don't just wrap the `(image, labels)` pair into a `lambda` but rather wrap the entire construction of the input into a function so that when the `Estimator` runs `input_fn` as a side effect of all the API calls all the input operations and tensors would be created in context of the correct `Graph`.